# Rails 5 - How to have shared data across multiple tenants in apartment gem?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, multi-tenant

In rails 5, I am working on multi-tenancy feature using `apartment` gem. I have to show the common dropdown data to all the tenants but it is not working.

Eg: I have `cities` list. Two tenants are created, both should get the same `cities` list. But the list is not displaying even if data is presence.

Added gem is,

```
apartment (1.2.0)
```

In database.yml,

```
default: &default
adapter: postgresql
pool: 5
encoding: UTF-8
database: TestApp
username: sample
password: pwd123

development:
  <<: *default
  host: localhost
```

How can I show the common city's list for all the tenants?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this, you need to have the model: `City` shared across tenants, and you can do so by configuring `config/initializers/apartment.rb` file.

Add/Edit the following line in the said file:

```
config.excluded_models = %w{ City }
```

Note: Don't forget to restart your server after you modify this file.

The reason why your code wasn't working: each tenant will have its own set of tables, and the table named `cities` will be different in each tenant.

Comment: Thank You. Its working fine. But there is one more issue, as an admin how can I get each tenant's data? Because admin should get all the reports.

Comment: To get data - that is not shared across multiple tenants - from a particular tenant, you will have to switch to that apartment, and then get the data, and then re-switch to the tenant you were using before.

Comment: An admin should be able to get all the data at a time. Is it possible without switching?

Comment: If you want to get all the data without switching, why don't you have all that data in a shared model?

Comment: because admin is a specific use case outside of the normal operation of an app (it's a separate app that combines schemas).

Comment: Did you solve this? Is there a clean way to get data of each tenant without having to iterate trough each tenant with `switch` method?